# Refresh UIView for drawRect?

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to refresh a UIView which will subsequently call drawRect?

EDIT:

I am doing `[view setNeedsDisplay]` however it doesn't appear to be working! Or at least my NSLog in drawRect isn't displaying.

EDIT2:

Please see comments of selected answer for the gory details! Number one tip: Make sure it's *property* linked!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes! Just call

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

from your view controller, or  `[self setNeedsDisplay]` directly from `UIView`, if you're using a subclass.

EDIT: make sure you're calling this on the correct `view`. The code above will call the `view` property of the view controller you're calling it from; this isn't necessarily correct, though it depends on your needs.

Also, make sure that the outlet is connected in Interface Builder, if you're creating this view in a nib file.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be working! Or at least my NSLog in drawRect isn't displaying.

Comment: Is that line of code you added getting called? Check with NSLog, or with a breakpoint.

Comment: Time Machine has a good point -- `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` is going to act on the `view` property, so be careful if you're talking about a different view, here. (odds are it's different, if you're subclassing.)

Comment: I'm almost certain. In the controller, I do : `[myView setNeedsDisplay];`. From here, the header file states `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MyView *myView;`. Then MyView has `@interface MyView : UIView`. I don't see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the UIView's outlet is connected properly, in Interface Builder? Sometimes the connection gets broken by accident.

Comment: In the Interface Builder when I click on the UIView, under Class View Identity it says it is indeed a MyView. So very confused!

Comment: In the nib file, make sure that when you click the `MyView` instance and go to the connections inspector (Command-2), you see a referencing outlet to `File's Owner`. If not, click that little circle and drag the line over to File's Owner. When you release, select the right property.

Comment: You're absolutely on the money. It seems I only added MyView to the Class View Identity, I never linked it. Thanks a lot, Sam.

Comment: No worries... it's one of the more frustrating problems, since you barely get any indication that the connection didn't happen!

Comment: You can add setNeedsDisplay on DidSet to your attribute